# WCF Data service and url parameters

Tags: wcf-data-services, url-parameters

I created a Service `service.svc` adding an WCF Service item in my Visual Studio Project. It´s defined followings:

```
public class Service : DataService<MyContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Items", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
        Email.SendErrorToDeveloper(args.Exception);
        base.HandleException(args);
    }
}
```

And the Context:

```
public class MyContext
{

    public IQueryable<Item> Items
    {
        get {
            return something;
        }
    }
}
```

As definition the service is consumed calling `http://localhost:53407/Service.svc/Items`.

I'm lookung if there is a way to add parameters to the url, in order to use them on server side in order to filter items. For example `http://localhost:53407/Service.svc/Items?year=2019`
Is it possible? How?

I found a [this](http://ashwini47-tts.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-parametrized-queryinterceptor-in.html) but I was looking for a solution where I can use the parameters in the `MyContext` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution:

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
{
    CurrentDataSource.YourCustomVariable = DoWhatYouNeet(args.OperationContext);
    base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
}
```

The WCF Service allows to intercept each call by overriding `OnStartProcessingRequest` which passes the request arguments including `DataServiceOperationContext` where we find basically everything.